# What are the advantages of running specflow selenium tests in release pipeline instead of build pipeline

Tags: selenium, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, specflow

I was executing specflow selenium tests in azure build pipeline which is working fine. But someone forced me to run these tests in the release pipeline instead of build pipelines by taking artifacts from the build pipeline.

I am not deploying any application to the server or any other machine. My release pipeline only runs the selenium tests.

**I am wondering why should I create a release pipeline if I can do this is in build pipeline itself.**

Comment: Build = build your app.  are tests building the app? no, they test it.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk an argument can be made for certain core-functionality unit tests to run in the build pipline. Acceptance level tests as specflow selenium tests should be, are most definitely not in that category.

Comment: @Sandesh A D Not get your latest information, is the following explanation helpful for you?If yes,you could [Accept one as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues . Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In continuous integration, focus is getting an automated good build out with basic build verification tests while continuous deployment is focused heavily on testing and release management flows.

Typically you will run unit tests in your build workflow, and functional tests in your release workflow after your app is deployed (usually to a QA environment).

The official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops) also recommends running Selenium tests in the release pipeline

Answer (score 2):

Running your Selenium tests in the build pipeline has following disadvantages:

- In most cases Selenium tests are much slower than e.g. simple unit tests, which increases the time of the build pipeline. But you want a fast build pipeline to continue with your work.
- If your tests are not stable you will break the build which is IMHO a no-go.

---

But in some cases it makes sense to execute a small set of Selenium tests during the build pipeline (if not covered with other tests).

This makes sense if you have a big product or when the build pipeline takes very long. You don't want to wait a few hours to get a successful build in your release pipeline where all tests fail because some basic functionallity does not work.

Comment: The solution which I am building in the build pipeline is just the automation test solution. We have a separate solution and builds for web application code which we deploy onto the server.